# How can I pass a parameter to a WCF Data Service and switch connection string based on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, connection-string, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service, which works fine. But now I want it to be able to use a different database based on a parameter that is sent by the consumer of my data service.

Concrete example: a client from US that uses the data service passes 'US' as a parameter, and so the data service uses the US database. Another client from Belgium that uses the data service passes 'BE' as a parameter, so the data service uses the BE database. Of course all databases have same schemas.

Currently my client uses the data service like:

```
var qclient = new QueryServiceReference.Complaint_Entities(new Uri("http://localhost:60642/QueryService.svc"));
```

But how would it be possible to add a parameter to this? And how can I check this parameter in the data service?

So my question is: how to pass a parameter to a WCF data service?

EDIT: I found a way, but I don't know if it's the best method to do it. Before doing the request, I add the parameter to the request header:

```
 var qclient = new QueryServiceReference.Complaint_Entities(new Uri("http://localhost:60642/QueryService.svc"));
 qclient.SendingRequest += new EventHandler<System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequestEventArgs>(qclient_SendingRequest);
 var cat = qclient.Categories.ToList();

static void qclient_SendingRequest(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequestEventArgs e)
{
   e.RequestHeaders.Add("Culture", "nl-BE");            
}
```

In the data service, I can then use it to set the connection string:

```
protected override Complaint_Entities CreateDataSource()
{
    var culture = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Culture"];   
    // set connectionString based on culture
    return new Complaint_Entities(connectionString);    
}
```

Thanks,
L

Comment: sure, why not? give it a try and if you have any issue, come back and raise a specific question

Comment: I have tried several things, otherwise I would't ask it here! Thanks anyway for the effort of writing this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found how to do it, here's how.

The client has to send the parameter before doing the query, which he can do by adding it to the request header as follows:

```
  var client = new QueryServiceReference.Complaint_Entities(new Uri("http://localhost:60642/QueryService.svc"));
  client.SendingRequest += (o, eventArgs) => eventArgs.RequestHeaders.Add("Culture", "nl-BE");
  var result = client.Categories.ToList();
```

In the data service, you then can set the connection string to be used depending on this parameter by overriding the CreateDataSource method:

```
public class QueryService : DataService<Complaint_Entities>
{
    protected override Complaint_Entities CreateDataSource()
    {
        var culture = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Culture"];
        string connectionStringName = string.Format("name=Complaint_Entities_{0}", culture);
        return new Complaint_Entities(connectionStringName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is entirely possible. You can add a name to each connection string you have and then select that connectionstring based on a passed variable.

//In your web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDefault" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=G14DEV;PASSWORD=Password;USER ID=UserId; Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
    <add name="ApplicationDefault" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=G14DEV;PASSWORD=Password;USER ID=UserId; Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
<connectionStrings>
```

//In your code

```
public void Connect(string user)
{
    switch(user)
    {
        case "Default":
        {
            m_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDefault"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        }
        case "Oracle":
        {
            m_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDefault"].ConnectionString;

            break;
        }
    }

    //now connect to the database
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this I know, but I don't know how to pass a parameter to a data service.

Comment: in that case I would raise a question 'how do I pass a parameter to a WCF data service'. this isolates your issue and removes the noise of the surrounding requrement. As you say, you know how to do everything you need, apart from pass the parameter.

Comment: why have you left the stuff in regarding switching the connection string? you said you know how to do that

Comment: I have added another answer that I believe should supply you with the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you are talking about a normal data service where you create your own connection. In the web.config keep the server name as a token say %DBSERVER% and replace this with the ipaddress or server name based on the request.

Answer (score 0):

WCF does nothing if you as the developer don't write code in it. Thus, **you are in charge of everything in WCF**.

To do this, simply check the variable in URL:

```
string countryCode = Request["country-code"]; 
// countryCode may be something like 'US'
```

Now, you can load a connection string from your web.config file, based on the value of `countryCode` and set the connection string of your Data Access Layer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but how can you pass this parameter to a wcf data service?

Answer (score 0):

That is fairly easy, all you have to do is to create a proper data context depending on the parameter value:

```
switch ( parameterValue ) {
   case "US" : datacontext = new ....( "US connectionstring" );
   case "EN" : datacontext = new ....( "BE connectionstring" );
}
```

However, there's a caveat and it's **authentication**.

You have to design a mechanism to authenticate your requests so that it is impossible for US users to craft requests to BE database and vice versa.

Comment: In fact I want to know how to pass this parameter to the data service?

Comment: At least four options: 1) build connection string automatically depending on request userhostaddress (poor, as ip addresses tend to change) 2) add an explicit parameter on WCF method's contract 3) add a soap header 4) add a http header.

Comment: Yes, just found it, I used the request header.